# Creating a list of global variables from C++ source file

Tags: c++, linux, ctags, nm

I'm now working on problem, its statement - generate text file with list of all declared global variables in .CPP file.

I came up to several ideas, first one:

Try to use ctags, so I wrote some short script:

```
while read line
do
echo $line
printf "%s" $line >> report.txt
ctags -x --c++-kinds=v --file-scope=no "{$line}" | sort | sed "/const/d" | awk '{printf " %s", $1}' >> report.txt
printf "\n" >> report.txt
done < cpp_source_file_list.txt
```

This piece of code gets filename of .cpp source file from cpp_source_file_list.txt, scans it for global variables (ignoring const) and write report "filename [list of variables].
The main problem I've encountered is that ctags acts very strange ignoring in some cases STL types.

E.g it can exclude line ike "vector v;", but include "std::vector v;".

Are there any ways to fix such issue? Trying to use ctags -I ./id.txt additional key and make manually list of identifiers to override, but it brings also incorrect results.

The second way:

Use nm command, like:

```
nm builtsource.o | grep '[0-9A-Fa-f]* [BCDGRS]'
```

But in this case I recieve unnecessary information, like:

```
0000000000603528 B M 
0000000000603548 B N 
0000000000603578 B _ZSt3cin@@GLIBCXX_3.4 <- (!)
0000000000603579 B _ZSt4cout@@GLIBCXX_3.4 <- (!)
0000000000603748 B t
```

And now I have no idea how to imporve one of these methods to recieve correct information about the list of declared global variables from arbitrary .cpp source file. I would be gladful to hear any suggestion on this problem.

Comment: C++ is "kind of" hard to parse, so using an external tool like ctags is necessary. However sedding for 'const' won't get you anywhere near ignoring const global, it can be a non-const pointer to const or even a name like 'constant'.

Comment: Sure, I agree about sedding regular expression, it was a sort of naive solution.

Comment: You would be at home with a good C++ parser which can give you a complete AST. Eclipse CDT has a decent parser but it isn't designed to work standalone (for reasons which elude me). You'd have to make an Eclipse plug-in to use it. I wonder how difficult would it be to generate an AST using GCC or Clang's internals

Comment: I wasn't far off with Clang! http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/group__CINDEX__CPP.html this might help you (can't give details since I haven't ever used it)

Comment: Thanks! I will try all ways ^)

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to leverage [Doxygen](http://www.doxygen.org/) to implement this. Doxygen can parse a C++ file and generate an XML file that captures all of the variables encountered in the file. Specifically, if you set the following configuration options:

```
EXTRACT_ALL= YES
GENERATE_TAGFILE= doxygen.tag
```

Given an input file like:

```
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

std::vector<int> s1;
vector s2;
```

You can generate an output `doxygen.tag` file with the following content:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='ISO-8859-1' standalone='yes' ?>
<tagfile>
  <compound kind="file">
    <name>input.cpp</name>
    <path>C:/Users/haney/tmp/tmp55/</path>
    <filename>input_8cpp</filename>
    <namespace>std</namespace>
    <member kind="variable">
      <type>std::vector&lt; int &gt;</type>
      <name>s1</name>
      <anchorfile>input_8cpp.html</anchorfile>
      <anchor>93b3bd32f5b6bff31bc4052716ddd444</anchor>
      <arglist></arglist>
    </member>
    <member kind="variable">
      <type>vector</type>
      <name>s2</name>
      <anchorfile>input_8cpp.html</anchorfile>
      <anchor>8feb4a508135e43a72f227568b755a07</anchor>
      <arglist></arglist>
    </member>
  </compound>
  <compound kind="namespace">
    <name>std</name>
    <filename>namespacestd.html</filename>
  </compound>
</tagfile>
```

Once you have the XML file, you should be able to extract out the information you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you for great working solution. Is there way to make Doxy not print out blocks with "kind" attribute being different from "file" or "variable"? There are situations when you get tons of blocks with member-kind's equal to "function", "typedef", etc. It'll be nice to get rid of these in .tag file.

Comment: Please note, everyone: Doxygento recognizes variable declared like "int a(0);" as a function "a" with "<arglist>(0)</arglist>".

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility would be to develop a GCC plugin or a [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/) extension for that precise purpose. You'll need to understand some of the details of GCC internal representations (Gimple and Tree).

The advantage of customizing GCC (with a plugin in C or an extension in MELT) is that you work on the exact compiler internals (after preprocessing and parsing). However, this will take you some effort.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider using [GCC-XML](http://www.gccxml.org/), probably with something else on top (like [pygccxml](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pygccxml)) to make things easier to navigate. I've successfully used this combination for similar code extraction purposes.